# Implementing a custom objective function for CatBoostRegressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, catboost

I'm using CatBoostRegressor for a supervised learning problem and I would like to use a custom objective function, but I do not know how to implement it in a way that is fully compatible with CatBoost and optimized for computational efficiency.

I was facing a trade-off between choosing RMSE (root mean squared error) and MAE (mean absolute error), so I have defined a custom objective function in an attempt to take the best of both worlds.

RMSE tends to produce "unbiased" estimators, because minimizing the RMSE over a set of numbers results in finding its mean. On the other hand, it tends to penalize a small number of large errors more heavily than a large number of small errors. Here's an example with two data points: if the errors are [5, 5], then the RMSE is 7.07, while if the errors are [0, 10] the RMSE is 10.

MAE has the advantage of penalizing a small number of large errors and a large number of small errors equally (in the example above, both [5, 5] and [0, 10] have a MAE=5). On the other hand, it tends to produce biased estimators, because minimizing the MAE over a set of numbers results in finding its median, which can be significantly different from the mean if there are outliers.

I would like to define a cost function that takes the best of both worlds:

1) My cost function should penalize a small number of large errors and a large number of small errors equally, just like MAE

2) My cost function should tend to produce unbiased estimators: minimizing my cost function over a set of numbers should result in finding its mean, just like RMSE

The idea is to take the MAE and penalize the bias. Here is the Python code for the cost functions:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error

# Root mean squared error (RMSE)
def rmse(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))

# Mean absolute error (MAE)
def mae(y_true, y_pred):
    return mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)

# Custom loss function: mean absolute error + bias
def my_error_function(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.mean(np.abs(y_true - y_pred)) + np.abs(np.mean(y_true - y_pred))
```

RMSE and MAE are already implemented in CatBoost (https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/loss-functions-regression-docpage/). I have found a tutorial on implementing a custom loss function here https://github.com/catboost/tutorials/blob/master/custom_loss/custom_metric_tutorial.md, but I wasn't able to modify the cost function according to my formula, because it needs to be written in c++ (https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/521). I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: What exactly is your **issue** and your **question**?

Comment: My issue is that I was not able to implement this cost function as a custom objective for CatBoostRegressor. My question is how to implement it in a way that is fully compatible with CatBoost and computationally efficient (i.e., using c++ instead of Python, as suggested here https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/521)

Comment: Thank you Anna Veronika. I'm afraid I can't open the link: I get an error message "server not responding"

Comment: Please take a look on tutorial with example of how to implement your objective in catboost: https://github.com/catboost/tutorials/blob/master/custom_loss/custom_metric_tutorial.md

Comment: I've updated the link.